# C++ long integer oddities?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, long-integer

I'm brushing up on some beginner's algorithms as I familiarize myself with C++. There are already some bugs I have no idea where to start fixing.

1) The following gives me seg faults around the time when the `fib()` function returns its results. **EDIT: with inputs >= 9**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int fib(int n) {
    int fibs[] = {1, 1};    // dynamic array
    int i = 2;              // start at 3rd element
    while(i < n) {
        fibs[i] = fibs[i-2] + fibs[i-1];
        cout << "DEBUG: fibs[" << i << "] = " << fibs[i] << endl;
        i = i+1;
    }
    cout << "about to return to main()" << endl;
    return fibs[n-1];
}

int main() {
    cout << "\n================= Hello cruel world =================" << endl;
    cout << "Enter a number:  ";
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    cout << "fib(" << x << ") = " << fib(x) << endl;
    cout << "================ Goodbye cruel world ================\n" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise, the code works just fine, the numbers are found correctly. But 2) when I change the function to support long integers, it starts acting weird:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

long fib(int n) {
    long fibs[] = {1L, 1L};    // dynamic array
    int i = 2;                 // start at 3rd element
    while(i < n) {
        fibs[i] = fibs[i-2] + fibs[i-1];
        cout << "DEBUG: fibs[" << i << "] = " << fibs[i] << endl;
        i = i+1;
    }
    cout << "about to return to main()" << endl;
    return fibs[n-1];
}

int main() {
    cout << "\n================= Hello cruel world =================" << endl;
    cout << "Enter a number:  ";
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    cout << "fib(" << x << ") = " << fib(x) << endl;
    cout << "================ Goodbye cruel world ================\n" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
================= Hello cruel world =================
Enter a number:  7
DEBUG: fibs[2] = 2
DEBUG: fibs[0] = 1
DEBUG: fibs[1] = 30071067265
DEBUG: fibs[2] = 30071067266
DEBUG: fibs[14] = 0
about to return to main()
fib(7) = 140733637791872
================ Goodbye cruel world ================
```

It doesn't make **any** sense to me. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int fibs[] = {1, 1};
```

is equivalent to:

```
int fibs[2] = {1, 1};
```

In another word, the array `fibs`(in both programs) has only two elements, it's illegal to access `fibs[n]` if `n` is bigger than `1`.

Comment: This isn't the first time I've seen someone think that `[]` means unlimited size.  Perhaps there's a bad teacher or tutorial out there somewhere.

Comment: Oh crap. But how does it work for inputs smaller than 9 in my tests. Totally threw me off loop there, otherwise I would've caught it. Thanks.

Comment: @Kafeaulait It's **undefined behavior** that just **happens** to work. The same program may not work in another machine, you can never rely on it.

Answer (score 2):

In

```
long fibs[] = {1L, 1L};
```

the `[]` does not mean "as big as it needs to be", it means "count the number of initializers".  It's the same as

```
long fibs[2] = { 1L, 1L };
```

And the comment

```
// dynamic array
```

is just plain WRONG.

Comment: I must've been half-asleep while reading the tutorial or something, cause I swear I read "dynamic" somewhere. Business as usual then, proper declaration and fixed size at compile time.

Comment: @Kafeaulait: With the average quality of C++ tutorials, you're just as likely to have read it correctly...  Get a good book and learn about vectors; this isn't a good use-case for arrays.

Comment: It's a fine use case for an array.  Static over allocation is easy and still comfortably small.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers explain what's wrong. To fix it, you can declare `fibs` as a vector instead:

```
vector<int> fibs(n, 1);
```

which will construct a vector of n integers and initialize them all to 1. Replacing that single line of code should be all you need!

Comment: (And in an unrelated issue, you should handle n < 1 separately.)

Comment: Or you can just declare a big enough static array, considering that fibonacci numbers quickly grow too large for any primitive integral type.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will fail because fibs[2] doesn't exist!

This is not dynamic array by any mean. Its array of 2 long

```
long fibs[] = {1L, 1L};    // dynamic array
```